# Getting Sentiments Using Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have a big dataset of Negative/Positive/Neutral sentiments in different languages. I have one php api (based on Naive Bayes algorithm) to get sentiments based on the give dataset. There are two issues :-

1) It is extremely slow

2) It is not working properly for non English languages such as Chinese and Vietnamese

I am looking this solution in Elastic Search because ES is good at language handling and also it can handle huge dataset and we can use inbuilt tokenizers of ES.

Is there any way to implement sentiment engine based on Naive Bayes algorithm in Elastic Search?

Comment: Good read and food for thoughts: https://www.elastic.co/blog/quick-tips-negative-connotation-filter